# Is it safe to delete unused EFI partitions?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora, grub

So before I start I would like to clarify that I'm a complete newbie with all this so please don't mind if I'm senseless and please direct me to the right direction, So Earlier I dual booted `Fedora 32` with `windows 10` but after rebooting from Windows to Fedora I got an error on the `grub` menu saying `You need to load the kernel first`, So I thought the cause of this problem might be Windows because both Windows 10 and fedora's `bootloaders` were installed on the same `EFI partition` so I deleted the whole linux installation and reinstalled by creating another seperate `EFI partition`  for fedora and Voila! This time I did not face any errors on the grub menu but today I read that it's not good to have multiple `ESP's` on the same disk so I plugged in a `live usb` and converted my `fedora's` `EFI partition` into `FAT32` using `gparted` but now the `grub` menu's not appearing while booting my computer and on Windows 10 it's still showing two `ESP's` so my question is there any way I could solve this? or delete on of the `EFI` partitions without affecting Windows 10 bootloader.